# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having some issues with the GoogleMaps SDK in SwiftUI.
I manually installed the SDK, because cocoa pods don't work on my Mac.
But now I have building issues:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Ignoring file /Users/f4mdev/AndroidStudioProjects/fabTraceability/iosApp/iosApp/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore, file is universal (arm64) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture: /Users/f4mdev/AndroidStudioProjects/fabTraceability/iosApp/iosApp/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore

Ignoring file /Users/f4mdev/AndroidStudioProjects/fabTraceability/iosApp/iosApp/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase, file is universal (arm64) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture: /Users/f4mdev/AndroidStudioProjects/fabTraceability/iosApp/iosApp/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase

Ignoring file /Users/f4mdev/AndroidStudioProjects/fabTraceability/iosApp/iosApp/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps, file is universal (arm64) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture: /Users/f4mdev/AndroidStudioProjects/fabTraceability/iosApp/iosApp/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices
```

This is my Code I tried:

```swift
import UIKit 
import GoogleMaps
import SwiftUI
struct GoogleMapsView: UIViewRepresentable {
   private let zoom: Float = 15.0
   func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
      let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
      let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
      return mapView
}
```

And here are the "OTHER LINKER FLAGS"
[image: other linker flags]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps package doesn't support Apple Silicon. Running the app on an actual device or running xcode in rosetta should work.